# Remove rows from numpy matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, delete-row

I have a list of integers which represent positions in a matrix (`centre`). For example,

```
centre = [2, 50, 100, 89]
```

I also have two numpy matrices, `X` and `Y`. I need to delete all of the rows from the matrix if the number is in the `centre`. I can do this:

```
for each in centre:
  x = numpy.delete(x, (each), axis=0)
```

However, the numbers will all be out as the index's will all be out. So, how can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do the `delete` in one call:

```
In [266]: B
Out[266]: 
array([[ 2,  4,  6],
       [ 8, 10, 12],
       [14, 16, 18],
       [20, 22, 24]])
In [267]: B1=np.delete(B,[1,3],axis=0)
In [268]: B1
Out[268]: 
array([[ 2,  4,  6],
       [14, 16, 18]])
```

You question is a little confusing.  I'm assuming that you want to delete rows by index number, not by some sort of content (not like the list `find`).

However if you must iterate (as with a list) do it in reverse order - that way indexing doesn't get messed up.  You may have to sort the indices first (`np.delete` doesn't require that).

```
In [269]: B1=B.copy()
In [270]: for i in [1,3][::-1]:
     ...:     B1=np.delete(B1,i,axis=0)
```

A list example that has to be iterative:

```
In [276]: B1=list(range(10))
In [277]: for i in [1,3,5,7][::-1]:
     ...:     del B1[i]
In [278]: B1
Out[278]: [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 9]
```

=============

With a list input like this, `np.delete` does the equivalent of:

```
In [285]: mask=np.ones((4,),bool)
In [286]: mask[[1,3]]=False
In [287]: mask
Out[287]: array([ True, False,  True, False], dtype=bool)
In [288]: B[mask,:]
Out[288]: 
array([[ 2,  4,  6],
       [14, 16, 18]])
```